# Why does python's dictionary iteration seemingly work with a copy?

Tags: python, iterator, copy, items

I am confused how python is iterating through this dictionary. From python's documentation, the itervalues returns an iterator over the dictionary's values.

```
dict = {"hello" : "wonderful", "today is" : "sunny", "more text" : "is always good"}

for x in dict.itervalues():
    x = x[2:]   

print dict
```

This prints out the original dictionary unchanged. Why is that? If I am saying the value at position x is "blabla", why is it not getting set?

Comment: +1 for the good question. It threw me of for a second.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has nothing to do with strings or lists. The devil is in how the `for` is unfolded.

Doing

```
for x in d.iteritems():
    # loop body
```

is more-or-less equivalent to doing

```
iter = d.itervalues()
while True:
    try:
        x = next(iter)
        # loop body
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

So with this in mind it's not very hard to see that we are just reassigning `x`, which holds a result from a function call.

```
iter = d.itervalues()
while True:
    try:
        x = next(iter)

        x = 5 # There is nothing in this line about changing the values of d
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Comment: Thanks, this has clarified it for me. I wish the python docs would explain things in more detail such as the intricacies of the for statement and various methods.

Answer (score 5):

The only thing the line

```
x = x[2:]
```

does is creating the string slice `x[2:]` and rebinding the name `x` to point to this new string.  It does not change the string `x` pointed to before.  (Strings are immutable in Python, they can't be changed.)

To achieve what you actually want, you need to make the dictionary entry point to the new string object created by the slicing:

```
for k, v in my_dict.iteritems():
    my_dict[k] = v[2:]
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with strings being immutable; if I replace `"hello":"wonderful"` with `"hello":[1,2]` it works the same.

Comment: @Mark: I also gave the real reason of the behaviour -- the fact that strings are immutable is rather a side note.  It does affect the solution though -- if values were lists, you could use `for x in my_dict: del x[:2]` to achieve the desired behaviour.

Comment: @Emil: I don't understand your comment.  Is it related to my answer in any way?  Or to my comment?  Is this your downvote?

Comment: @Sven: Sorry, after reading it a few more times it's actually correct.

Answer (score 1):

As [Sven Marnach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016696/why-does-pythons-dictionary-iteration-seemingly-work-with-a-copy/7016735#7016735) points out, strings are immutable and you are just rebinding `x` to a new string created by the slice notation. You can demonstrate that `x` *does* point to the same object in the dictionary by using `id`:

```
>>> obj = 'hello'

>>> id(obj)
<<< 4318531232

>>> d = {'key': obj}   

>>> [id(v) for v in d.values()]
<<< [4318531232]

>>> [id(v) for v in d.itervalues()]
<<< [4318531232]

>>> [(k, id(v)) for k, v in d.items()]
<<< [('key', 4318531232)]

>>> [(k, id(v)) for k, v in d.iteritems()]
<<< [('key', 4318531232)]
```

You can use `iteritems` to iterate over key and value together to do what you want:

```
for k,v in dict.iteritems():
    dict[k] = v[2:]
```